# How can I access my windows 7 drives in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

Hi I just installed Ubuntu over my Windows 7 installation. Now only Ubuntu is installed on my system. But the thing is I want to access my other 3 drives which I have in windows 7 that contains my personal stuff: movies, pictures etc.

I don't have any other operating system on my system so I want to use them on this drive. Please help.

How can I access these drives and show them on my computer?

Comment: @user271970 Do you have Ubuntu 13.04 or 14.04? You should see your NTFS drives in `nautilus` in the `devices` category in the sidebar.

Comment: don't you have them in nautilus file browser top left corner, in devices section?

Answer (score 0):

You can see your windows drives in Ubuntu from `files`. [image]
For example I have two drives on windows. They are shown as New volume and 172 GB volume.
[image] To browse them just click on them and they will open.
[image]